# Passing PHP variable to JavaScript with special characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button with an onclick function where i send several php variables to my javascript function. This all works fine except for when i have a ' within the text.

So i would have a button

```
<button onclick=\"selected_comp('" . preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $comp_row['comments']) . "')\"
```

then i would have a function

```
function selected_comp(comments){
console.log(comments);
}
```

I have tried preg_replace and json_encode but both give me errors (json_encode gives me error in general and with preg_replace it works most of the time but whenever this ' character is inside the comments it doesn't work. How can i make sure this gets treated as just plain text whatever character is inside.

> error: (index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From how your PHP code is written, if the text in `$comp_row['comments']` is `text` then the resulting JS code will be

```
<button onclick="selected_comp('text')">
```

(where I added the `<` and `>` for clarity).

Now if the text is `text with ' embedded` it will result in

```
<button onclick="selected_comp('text with ' embedded')">
```

Then you clearly see why it fires an error.

There are plenty of different solutions to avoid it, like the one suggested by @Terminus.
But maybe it's not easy to apply without deeply changing your PHP script structure.

So here is a suggestion which may appear a bit weird but keeps using your current code organization:

```
button onclick=\"selected_comp('" . 
str_replace(["\r", "\n", "'"], ["", "", "\\'"], $comp_row['comments']) . 
"')\"
```

First you can notice that I changed from `preg_replace()` to `str_replace()` (anyway `preg_replace()` was already overkill).

And the point is that now, not only `\r` and `\n` are replaced by "nothing" but also `'` is escaped.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your string to be valid javascript string that you can use inside your javascript code (in your example - pass the string to the `selected_comp` function) you should:

1. Make sure you don't have line-breaks in your string.
2. Make sure you don't have quotes inside your string (Note here it depends on the quotes you use in your code - single/double).

So you can:

1. `str_replace(["\r", "\n"], ['\r', '\n'], $comp_row['comments']);`
2. `str_replace("'", "\\'", $comp_row['comments']);`

And in your code:

```
<button onclick=\"selected_comp('". 
    str_replace("'", "\\'",
        str_replace(["\r", "\n"], ['\r', '\n'], $comp_row['comments'])
    ) .
"')\"
```

I used `'` because you used it in your original function.